In Selenium IDE, how could an element array position be captured to coordinate selection of related elements?
The Problem: I can have a list of linked elements, but they could be in a different order over time as the user adds or removes from the list. The linked name is unique, but it's related hamburger menu (3-dots) is not unique except in array position (see example image). Is there a way I could capture the array value of the uniquely titled linked element to associate and identify its related menu, date, status, and dashboard items?
What I'm trying to do: I'm trying to account for the fact that over time, this table list can increase and decrease, and positions change due to alphabetic sorting of the name. So, the tested case could be first, last, or in the middle.
What I've "attempted" to try: I'm trying to use execute script searching on javascript that may help, but I haven't been successful yet.


